# Why my function doesn't work?

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int exponent(int x){
    int n = 6;
    for (int i = 0 ;i<4 ;i++){
        n*=6;
    }
    return x;

}
void print_exponent(int x){

    cout<<"6^5 = "<<x<<endl;
}
int main () {
    int x;

    print_exponent(x);
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote 2 functions, first one to calculate 6^5, second one to print the value, when I run this, it prints wrong calculation (28), What's wrong with this function?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `x` argument? You never use it in the `exponent()` function, you have everything hard-coded.

Comment: You need to go back to the books and learn how functions and function arguments work.

Comment: @Barmar I'm a beginner, not an elite!

Comment: SO is not a tutoring service, you're expected to learn the basics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `exponent` function needs to return the `n` instead of `x` and in your `main()` you probably want to initialize the variable `x` to the value of function `exponent` with an argument of `5`:

```
int x = exponent(5);
```

prior to printing via:

```
print_exponent(x);
```

That being said, your `exponent` function is broken as the return value is always the same no matter the parameter value. Modify the `for` loop to be:

```
for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
    n *= 6;
}
```

And you probably want to check if the parameter is equal to `0`:

```
if (x == 0) {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @AdamEve Certainly not. I am sorry but SO is not a code writing service. What I can do is try to point you in the right direction and do the debugging. The rest is up to you.

Comment: Okay, I don't understand int x = exponenet(5) , where should I write this? in main function or where?

Comment: Please have a look at this [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) list to establish a frame of reference.

Answer (score 2):

You never call `exponent`. Instead you print the *uninitialized* and *indeterminate* value of `x`.

Besides, your `exponent` function returns the argument `x`, but it never modifies or assigns to `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `exponent` function is calculating with `n` and returns the unused `x`.
Besides that `int x;` needs to be initialized before calling `exponent(x);`